# "package mysql-server is not installed" even when it is installed

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, mysql, deb

I am trying to install a deb package running the command

> dpkg -i code/mydeb.deb

it gives an error saying

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openmrs:
 openmrs depends on mysql-server (>= 5.0); however:
  Package mysql-server is not installed.
```

I have lampp running on my OS. Running mysql commands like
`mysql` and `sudo mysql` does not give any error.

How can i overcome this error.

**UPDATE**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ankit# apt-cache policy mysql-server
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.2
  Version table:
     5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
     5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main i386 Packages
     5.5.27-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested to me in the comments I installed mysql-server and the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server` has now changed to but I still get the same error

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.2
  Candidate: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main i386 Packages
     5.5.27-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server`? (Please, [edit] the question to add this information.)

Comment: @edwin I have updated my question accordingly. can you help?

Comment: The `mysql-server` package is an empty package that depends on the current 'best' mysql-server-M.m package (e.g. `mysql-server-5.5`) so it is quite possible to have a running LAMP server without it. You could try just installing the empty package - it should succeed provided the package it depends on does not conflict with the already installed `mysql-server-5.5` I think

Comment: And how exactly do i install that empty package?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get -f install` can sometimes also help to install missing dependencies (run it directly after your `dpkg -i *.deb` command).